# Cannot install package: kernel missing Linux support

Tags: linux, kernel, freebsd, pkg

I'm trying to install Dwarf Fortress on my MacBook Air running FreeBSD 11.0 via `pkg install linux-dwarffortress`. Here is some background information:

```
root@machine0:~ # uname -a
FreeBSD machine0 11.0-RELEASE-p10 FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p10 #1 r319768: Sat Jun 10 07:03:28 CST 2017     root@machine0:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

During the installation, I got a `kernel missing Linux support` error:

```
[1/28] Installing linux-c6-expat-2.0.1_5...
Cannot install package: kernel missing Linux support
pkg: PRE-INSTALL script failed
```

I just updated my system today, [following the instructions of the FreeBSD handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/makeworld.html).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have `linux_enable="YES"` in your `rc.conf` file? See [this document](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/linuxemu-lbc-install.html) for more.

Comment: @RichardSmith Ahh I forgot I wasn't using Linux! Thanks for pointing this out. My machine is rebuilding the kernel, and I'll added that line after it finishes.

Comment: @SunQingyao Does this fix your problem? If so, you can close or delete your question. Or Richard Smith could leave an answer.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks, this works, though I'm still having an "Error opening xterm" problem, which should be dealt with in a new question. Would you consider making your comment an answer?

Comment: @FaheemMitha It does fix my problem, but I don't understand why should I close or delete my question? Because it's solved?

Comment: @SunQingyao You don't  have to. Closing or deleting is possibly appropriate if the question is based on user error, and is not generally useful to others. But this is a judgement call.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [dwarffortresswiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Installation#FreeBSD) before installing the `linux-dwarffortress` , you should install the required package to solve the `missing Linux support` error:

> FreeBSD
>
> Although there is no official version ported to FreeBSD, Dwarf Fortress can nevertheless be run using either Wine or FreeBSD's compatibility with Linux. However, **attempting to run the Linux version out of the blue will result in an error about missing library files**. Such files must be downloaded from special linux-compatible packages or ports; using your preferred installation method, install the following:
>
> `linux-c6` :

```
 sudo pkg install linux-c6-gtk2 linux-c6-sdl linux-c6-sdl_image linux-c6-sdl_ttf linux-c6-libGLU \
 linux-c6-openal-soft linux-c6-libsndfile linux-c6-alsa-plugins-oss
```

> `linux-f10`
>
> If you don't have the linux-c6 ports available in your system, you can still run Dwarf Fortress (albeit without sound) using the following packages:

```
 sudo pkg install linux-f10-alsa-lib linux-f10-atk linux-f10-cairo linux-f10-expat linux-f10-fontconfig \
 linux-f10-gtk2 linux-f10-jpeg linux-f10-pango linux-f10-png linux-f10-sdl linux-f10-sdl_image linux-f10-tiff \
 linux-f10-xorg-libs linux-sdl_ttf linux_base-f10 linux_dri linux-f10-libGLU
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `kldload linux64`